# Is it possible to track the sequence of event handlers as they fire?

Tags: events, excel, userform, excel-2002, vba

Using Excel 2002 and have a VBA "app" that has some UserForms.
The main UserForm contains a number of textboxes that fire various Enter/Exit events.

I am now running into a issue where one of the textbox exit events fires 2x in a row (I know because a messagebox appears each time).

Is there some means within Excel VBA to track all the events that fire and their sequence without writing code in every event/procedure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know the answer to your question, but inserting this code will help prevent firing unwanted events:

```
Application.EnableEvents = False   'avoid self firing events

  'run your code....

Application.EnableEvents = True    're-enable events
```

Comment: Thanks - that should do quit nicely.